# React-select Clear and Dropdown indicators order

Tags: react-select

Thank the author for this library, but i have one question:
How to change order of `Clear` and `Dropdown` indicators (i want: Dropdown - first, Clear - second)?

I know this indicators are in children prop, but how change order on render?
Or how I can add additional button for clear after Dropdown indicator?

Answer (score 1):

ClearIndicator and DropdownIndicator both are children of the IndicatorsContainer so that would be where the updates would have to be made.

One approach would be to first render a DropdownIndicator, then loop through the IndicatorContainer's children to find the DropdownIndicator, and remove it.

```
import React, { Children } from "react";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";

const IndicatorsContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const allowedChildren = Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return (child && child.type.name !== 'DropdownIndicator') ? child : null;
  });

  return (
    <components.IndicatorsContainer {...props}>
      <components.DropdownIndicator />
      {allowedChildren}
    </components.IndicatorsContainer>
  );
};

const CustomSelect = (props) => (
  <Select components={{ IndicatorsContainer }} {...props} />
)

export default CustomSelect;
```

Note: I found this SO question from the react-select issues page [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4220) where the user asked to move the DropdownIndicator and IndicatorSeparator to the left of the input which is a bit more complex but has a working codesandbox solution.

Comment: Hacky, but I'll take it, thanks!